# How to print the data from list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading file and creating list of the record but i don't know how to print them. 
Can you please help me how to do this?

```
fp = open('D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/code_11032020/latest_script/eureka_sqoop_emr_r.env', 'r')
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fp]
```

ouput

```
['CONDITIONS="1=1"', 'ENVIRONMENT=DEV', 'EC2_USER_HOME=/medaff/Scripts', 'AMPIL_LOCAL_MERGED_DIR=/medaff/eureka/RawLayer']
```

Now i want to print the data. 
If i type print(CONDITIONS) then it should print its value.

Comment: Instead of using `list` you can use `dictionary` to store data.

Comment: @Prudhvi can you please write sample code?

Comment: Can you add the data of file?

Comment: @Prudhvi i added the output

Comment: add the content of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the list use the following code to create the dictionary:

```
data = {}    
for line in lines:
    temp = line.split('=', 1)
    data[temp[0]] = temp[1]
print(data['CONDITIONS'])
## Output '1=1'
```

Comment: Not exactly what I would call a good practice to start a variable name by a capital letter, also there's a space between `line` and `split`

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_data(data):
    for line in lines:
        if data in line:
           print(line.replace(data+"=", ""))

print_data('CONDITIONS')
# "1=1"
```

Note that for your use case, a dictionary can be more suited.
Starting from your list, you can have a dictionary like so:

```
dictionary = {line.split("=", 1)[0]:line.split("=", 1)[-1] for line in lines}
```

To have the following output:

```
{'CONDITIONS': '"1=1"', 'ENVIRONMENT': 'DEV', 'EC2_USER_HOME': '/medaff/Scripts', 'AMPIL_LOCAL_MERGED_DIR': '/medaff/eureka/RawLayer'}
```

Now you can access "CONDITIONS" key simply with:

```
dictionary['CONDITIONS']
```

Comment: How to create dictionary?

Comment: @shivam have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Following function should do exactly what you want:

```py
def get_data_dict(l):
    data = {}
    l_split = [elem.split("=", 1) for elem in l]
    for key, value in l_split:
        data[key] = value

    return data
```

So for example you can use it like this:

```py
data = get_data_dict(l)

data['ENVIRONMENT']
```

and the output will be:

```
'DEV'
```